# C order of operations -- foo() + bar() -- must foo be called before bar?

Tags: c

In the following code:

```
int foo();
int bar();
int i;

i = foo() + bar();
```

Is it guaranteed by the C standard that `foo` is called before `bar` is called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there's no sequence point with `+`. There's actually a quote on the Wikipedia page about it that answers your question:

> Consider two functions f() and g(). In C and C++, the + operator is not associated with a sequence point, and therefore in the expression f()+g() it is possible that either f() or g() will be executed first.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_points

Answer (score 7):

It's unspecified, and in the case of C99 the relevant quotation is 6.5/3:

> Except as speciﬁed later (for the function-call `()`, `&&`, `||`, `?:`, and
>   comma operators), the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the
>   order in which side effects take place are both unspeciﬁed.

In your example, `foo()` and `bar()` are subexpressions of the full expression `i = foo() + bar()`.

The "later" for function calls isn't directly relevant here, but for reference it is 6.5.2.2/10:

> The order of evaluation of the function designator,the actual
>   arguments, and subexpressions within the actual arguments is
>   unspeciﬁed, but there is a sequence point before the actual call.

For `&&` it's 6.5.13/4:

> Unlike the bitwise binary & operator,the && operator guarantees
>   left-to-right evaluation; there is a sequence point after the
>   evaluation of the ﬁrst operand.

Since `+` is not in the list of operators at the top, `&&` and `+` are "unlike" in the same way that `&&` and `&` are "unlike", and this is precisely the thing you're asking about. Unlike `&&`, `+` does *not* guarantee left-to-right evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it is not.** The evaluation order of function and operator arguments is undefined.

The standard says only, that calls to `foo` and `bar` cannot be interleaved, which can happen when evaluating subexpressions without function calls.

Comment: @Pubby substitute function with operator here.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not defined.  From K & R page 200:

> the order of evaluation of expressions is, with certain exceptions, undefined, even if the subexpressions involve side effects.  That is, unless the definition of the operator guarantees that its operands are evaluated in a particular order, the implementation is free to evaluate operands in any order, or even to interleave their evaluation.

Page 205 of K & R describes the additive operators, and doesn't define the order of evaluator of the two operands.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer where I work is "If the order is important, the code is unmaintainable regardless of what the standard says will happen". If you must have foo() evaluated before bar(), explicitly evaluate foo() before bar(). The basis for this is  not every programmer knows the standards, and those that do don't know if the original author did.